# Enhance 2 functions in order to give correct output

Tags: c, function

I have written the following console application which asks the user to input a day.

I need some help in order to improve so that they give the correct answer for ALL days of the week.

If user inputs any other day apart from Monday, the output is "today", "yesterday", "tomorrow" with the respective days output below those headings.

The problem seems to be only Monday is not producing the correct output.

This is my code so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum  the_days {monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday, noday} day;

day yesterday (day today);
day tomorrow (day today);

char thedays[][10] = {"monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"};

day findDay(char string1[]);

void main(void)
{
    day today;
    char theDay[10];

    puts("Type the day (e.g. 'monday'");
    gets(theDay);

    today = findDay(theDay);

    if(today == noday)
    {
        puts("Error - invalid input - exiting");
        return;
    }

    printf("today    \tyesterday  \ttomorrow\n"
        "============================================\n");
    printf("%s\t %s \t %s\n", thedays[today],   thedays[yesterday(today)],thedays[tomorrow(today)]);
}

day findDay(char string1[])
{
    int i = 0;
    day thisday;

    for (i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        if (!strcmp(thedays[i],string1))
        {
            break;      
        }
    }
    thisday = (day)i;
    return thisday;
}

day yesterday(day today)
{
    day before;
    before = (day)(today- 1);
    return before;
}

day tomorrow(day today)
{
    day after;
    after = (day)(today + 1);
    return after;
}
```

Comment: For some sample input, what is the expected output, and the actual output? And have you tried to e.g. step through the code line by line in a debugger, to see what happens?

Comment: If user inputs any other day apart from Monday, the output is "today", "yesterday", "tomorrow" with the respective days output below those headings.
The problem seems to be only Monday is not producing the correct output.

Comment: I would say that Sunday would give you the wrong result as well. The reason that Monday gives you the wrong result is because then `yesterday` return `-1`, which is not valid in the `day` enumeration. How do you think you could fix this, so that it's the Sunday enumeration (value `6`) instead? In other words, how do you get from `-1` to `6`?

Comment: What is the day before monday ?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thank you, could you please explain a little more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get incorrect results with Monday and Sunday because your `yesterday` and `tomorrow` functions are not taking care of wraparound. You could fix these functions like this:

```
day yesterday(day today)
{
    day before = today > monday ? today - 1 : sunday;
    return before;
}

day tomorrow(day today)
{
    day after = today < sunday ? today + 1 : monday;
    return after;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a little further please - i have put in your code but i get errors.

Comment: Sorry - a couple of typos - now fixed.

Comment: Thanks @Paul R but i get the following errors:


'1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  Bug1.cpp
1>c:\users\david o'dea\desktop\bug1\bug1\bug1.cpp(54): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'day'
1>          Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast)
1>c:\users\david o'dea\desktop\bug1\bug1\bug1.cpp(60): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'day'
1>          Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast)'

Comment: Oh - you tagged your question as **C** but you're compiling your code as **C++**! Since you're not using any C++ features in your code I suggest you rename `bug1.cpp` to `bug1.c` and then the errors should go away.

Comment: Great - thanks, the errors have gone but now I have a problem with 'gets_s' on line 21:
1>  Bug1.c
1>c:\users\david o'dea\desktop\bug1\bug1\bug1.c(21): error C2198: 'gets_s' : too few arguments for call

Comment: I don't see `gets_s` anywhere in your code? (Note that you should ideally be using `fgets`, since `gets` is unsafe.)

Comment: OK - I see that `gets_s` is a non-standard Microsft-ism - it looks like you need `gets_s(theDay, sizeof(theDay) - 1);`.

Comment: That was a warning, not an error, but it's true that `gets` is unsafe for general use. You can either switch back to `gets` for now or use the `gets_s` fix I noted above. (Note that `fgets` is a more portable solution, but one step at a time for now...)